# How do you assign a shortcut key to Command Prompts so that it can open multiple windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, keyboard-shortcuts

On every Windows machine that I've ever owned (or used at work), I've assigned a Shortcut key to open a Command Prompt window on entering the shortcut key.

If you enter this shortcut key several times then you get several command prompt windows opening concurrently - which is what I expect.

My latest Windows home laptop came with Windows 7 & I was still able to set it up to perform this function. My laptop @ work was until recently an XP machine, which again I setup to behave in this way.

However, when my laptop @ work was recently upgraded to a Windows 7 machine, & I defined the shortcut key as usual, it now opens only one command prompt window. As long as this window is open, any further use of the shortcut key merely switches to that open window.

How can I get the intended behavior of opening multiple window? I suspect that it may have something to do with the registry but I haven't been able to narrow it down thus far. Any ideas?

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser.com, you are more likely to get a response there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is pin the command prompt to your taskbar and then press WinLogo +  where number is what number (counting from left to right) on the bar. So if you command prompt is 4th from the left to right it would be Winlogo + 4 you can spam that all you want and it will keep opening new windows.

It would not open new windows if you were to just right click on the command prompt from start menu and click properties then goto the shortcut tab and set a keyboard shortcut, that would only open the command prompt once, maybe twice if you spam it fast enough, but then it would not open any more as the windows are active. So the best way is the first method above. I hope this helps.